# How to make navigation bar elements darken except hovered list item

Tags: html, css

So, I wanted to implement navigation effect like [here](https://nueva-demo.squarespace.com/). I want the whole `nav` to darken except the hovered `li`.

I tried the following code

```css
.nav-bar ul {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  padding-left: 2em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.nav-bar ul:hover {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.nav-bar ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2em;
}

.nav-bar ul li:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav-bar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-bar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I expected the result to be as in the link but the outcome does not "undarken" the hovered li.

I figured out the solution, here is the edited CSS code:

```
.nav-bar ul {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  padding-left: 2em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.nav-bar ul:hover li:not(:hover) {
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.nav-bar ul li {
  position: relative;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2em;
}

.nav-bar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Your code snippet does not work correctly. Could you check it please, otherwise nobody can see your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use javascript or jquery to achieve this. Please refer below sample to see how we can add effects on hover.

```js
$("li").hover(function() {
  $(this).siblings().children('a').css('opacity', 0.7).css('transition-duration', '0.2s').css('color', 'black'); // add css props here for unhover effect
  $(this).children('a').css('z-index', 1).css('opacity', 0.7).css('transition-duration', '0.2s').css('color', 'red'); // add css props here to add hover effect
}, function() {
  // revert all changes here when hover out
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav-bar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```